# Make parent div expand beyond window to wrap all children

Tags: html, css

While this sounds like a pretty simple problem to solve, I have not found a way to do this without using Javascript.

Consider this example: https://jsfiddle.net/oopssam8/1/

```
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

div > div {
  width: 200px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

body > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

As you can see, the red boxes expand beyond the window. Each box is 200px wide, and so when when inspecting their parent, I expect to see a width of 2000px (there are 10 red boxes). The computed width of the parent div does not extent beyond the window width.

Is there any way I could make the parent div expand beyond the window and wrap all child element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the value of the width on the container div to: `width: fit-content;` (with additional vendor prefixes, like in the example below)

Here's the working example:

```css
div > div {
  width: 200px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

body > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```